# Windows Hook to catch WM_MDITILE (using good old C++)

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I know everyone is off to great mobile or web type work. Well, I'm stuck here on some good old C++. Here's whats bugging me.

I want my application to do a certain thing when the user presses the menu "Tile Vertically" in another app (in another process). (Many apps have a menu "Windows" and underneath that is a sub menu "Tile Vertically"). I'm under the assumption that I need to setup a global hook using SetWindowsHookEx. I tried doing that using "WH_CALLWNDPROC" and was only able to hook to "in process" messages, not "out of process". I tried WH_GETMESSAGE as well. I tried catching WM_SIZE, that also did not work out of process.
In fact, even in process, WM_SIZE didn't work on all windows , only on some of them.

So now there are a few questions:

1- What is the right type of hook (WH_CALLWNDPROC or WH_GETMESSAGE or perhaps one of the other hook types that can be used)?

2- How do I get it to pick up out of process messages?

3- Any tips where I can get sample hook code for WM_MDITILE?

4- I tried doing a keyboard hook and that worked, why doesn't this work?

5- I'm using a win 32 dll with the DllMain code below. Is there anything wrong with it?

```
HINSTANCE hinst;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        //
        // Capture the application instance of this module to pass to
        // hook initialization.
        //
        if (hinst == NULL)
        {
            hinst = hModule;
        }

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Any tips or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try WH_MSGFILTER or WH_SYSMSGFILTER?
It looks like these IDs are dedicated to monitor messages generated as a result of an input event in a dialog box, message box, menu, or scroll bar.

For more details reffer to link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx